# Folder invisible from VS2012, but visible in Explorer, Powershell, and Open.. dialog in Notepad

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, filesystems, windows-server-2012

I installed VS2012 on Windows Server 2012.  I also installed Microsoft Certificate Services on the same machine with the goal of customizing the Classic ASP pages there.

When I use the "Open Website" dialog box, I'm unable to see the folder.  The results are the same if I'm elevated or not.

[image]

However I can view the folder in powershell

[image]

Why can't I view the folder in VS2012?

I also created a folder called certsrv-powershell and it also doesn't appear

Answer (score 2):

Because VS 2012 is a 32-bit exe and the c:\windows\system32 folder it uses is really at c:\windows\syswow64.  If you fire up an x86 PowerShell prompt and create dirs under system32, VS would see them.